# How to refer to model class (name) from html form to views.py with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want users to be able to download a Django model which is being displayed in the app. There can be many types of models, therefore I want to generalize my code. Currently I let users download the model in excel by means of the following code in HTML:

```
<form id="downloadfile" method="post" action="{% url 'download_file' filename='Irrelevant.xlsx'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="Plant" name="database" />
    <input type="submit" name="downloadfile"  class="btn btn-success" value="Download Plant">
</form>
```

My views.py:

```
# Define function to download excel file using template
from database.models import Plant

def download_file(request, filename=''):
    if 'downloadfile' in request.POST:
        db_name = request.POST.get('database')
        #How to specify Plant database?
        response = xlsx_generator(Plant, db_name) #db_name is used to name the .xlsx file and is just a string.
        return response

    else:
        #some other things to do for other post requests
```

As you can see, I import the Plant model from `database.models`, and refer to it manually in the xlsx_generator. What I would like to do is refer to this imported model from the posted form so that I don't have to refer to it manually anymore. e.g.
`db_model = request.POST.get('database')` and then `response = xlsx_generator(db_model, db_name)` where db_model refers to Plant model. Can this be achieved? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps


def get_all_models():
    model_name_list = []
    installed_apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS[6:]
    # just exclude system app that is not installed by you
    for app in installed_apps:
        app_config = apps.get_app_config(app)
        for model in app_config.get_models():
            model_dict = dict()
            model_dict['name']: model.__name__
            model_dict['value']: model.__name__.lower()
            model_name_list.append(model_dict)
    return model_name_list
```

It's a kind of dynamic way to get all models from different apps in your Django project.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Somehow this code returns an empty list for me (```INSTALLED_APPS``` is shown in white, as is ```apps``` so I guess these can't be found, whereas ```INSTALLED_APPS``` is definitely present in ```settings.py```). However, it does give me the idea to create a dictionary from the models as such: ```model_dict={"plant": Plant, "some_other_model": Some_Other_Model}``` and later on do ```model_dict[db_name]``` which will return ```<class 'database.models.Plant'>``` and therefore this model as desired excel for download :)!

Comment: Ok. ```INSTALLED_APPS[6:]```, suits my needs. However, ```NameError: name 'apps' is not defined. Did you mean: 'app'?```

Comment: Ok. It seems ```from django.apps import apps``` needs to be added, and then some minor modifications.

Comment: I have just modified the solution. Just please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to input of @Md.Imam Hossain Roni, I now have an elegant solution to retrieve model of interest from hidden input in HTML form and pass back model information through response.

views.py

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from database.utils import xlsx_generator
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_all_models():
    installed_apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS[6:]
    model_dict={}
    # just exclude system app that is not installed by you
    for app in installed_apps:
        app_config = apps.get_app_config(app)
        for model in app_config.get_models():
            model_dict[model.__name__] = model
    return model_dict

# Define function to download excel file using template
def download_file(request, filename=''):
    if 'downloadfile' in request.POST:
        db_name = request.POST.get('database')
        model_name_list=get_all_models()
        response = xlsx_generator(model_name_list[db_name], db_name)
        return response
```

For completeness settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'database',
    'project_management',
]
```

I do wonder though, that if the model base gets very big, if this dictionary has same size of entire sqlite database, and if this will end up being problematic...